# Download a certain file from a certain directory using Wget in c

Tags: c

I am trying to write a basic script in C that I can use to download files off of a webserver.  It would use wget, but I want to find a way where I can specify the directory and file that I want to download using a arguments.  I'm just very new to C and I don't know how that would work.  If anyone can show me how to write that or just point me in the write direction that would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: Do you know `printf`? Can you use `printf` to print the command-string you want to use? Then you should be able to do it using **`snprintf`** which "prints" to a string buffer which can be passed to the `system` function.

Comment: I was thinking I could also use strcypy in kind of the same way.  Here is an example.
`void download(){
    char dir = argv[1]
    char file = argv[2]
    strcpy("wget https://1.1.1.1/%s/%s", dir, file);
}`

Comment: That's not what [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) does. But it is what [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) paired with [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) will do.

Comment: Oh I just looked up how to use strcpy, it would be something like 
`strcpy(download, "https://1.1.1.1/%s/%s", dir, file);
system(download);`

Comment: But overall I think that snprintf would be easier.

Comment: Again, that's not what `strcpy` does! It doesn't do any string formatting at all. It's just plain copying from one string to another. `snprintf(download, sizeof download, "wget https://1.1.1.1/%s/%s", dir, file)` is what you need (assuming that `download` is an *array* and not a pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to this is, as I already commented, to use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) to format the command-string, and then pass it to [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) for execution.

Something like

```
void download(const char *path, const char *file)
{
    char command[1024];

    // Create the command
    snprintf(command, sizeof command, "wget https://1.1.1.1/%s/%s", path, file);

    // Execute the command
    system(command);
}
```

Comment: Oh okay I see, I was just a but confused on the use of `snprintf` but I get it not.  I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: Oh okay I apologize, I am extremely new here.  I accepted and up-voted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char    *joinstrings(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    char    *s3;

    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (NULL);
    if (!s1)
        return (strdup(s2));
    if (!s2)
        return (strdup(s1));
    if (!(s3 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)))))
        return (NULL);
    strcpy(s3, s1);
    strcat(s3, s2);
    return (s3);
}


    int main(int ac, char **av)
    {
        char *str;
        if (ac < 2)
            return (1);
        if (!(str = joinstrings("wget ", (const char *)av[1])))
            return (1);
        system(str);
        free(str);
        str = NULL;
        return (0);
    }
```

> $~> gcc p.c -o prog
>
> $~> ./prog https://website/folder/file.txt

The string containing the address and the file location is given in argument as a single parameter, but using a function to join strings you can do it the way you want,
using snprintf to fill a buffer as sayed in the comment on you'r post is also a good solution but it's less begginner friendly i guess

The function joinstrings will also be very helpful for you, you always have to concatenate strings when programming

**Just remember to check if it's result is not NULL, and also call function free on it when you are done using it, then set pointer to NULL**

Comment: Oh okay I see, thank you!  I realized that the question was a lot more basic then I first thought haha.

Comment: You're welcome, Can you upvote and select as answer if this helped you , and you're quesiton is answered :)